# Running Solr in read-only mode

Tags: solr

I think I'm missing something obvious here. I have to imagine a lot of people open up their Solr servers to other developers and don't want them to be able to modify the index.

Is there something in solrconfig.xml that can be set to effectively make the index read-only?

**Update for clarification:**
My goal is to use Solr with an existing Lucene index managed by another application. This works just fine, but I want to be sure Solr never tries to write to this index.

Comment: why do you say that "a lot of people open up their Solr servers to other developers"?

Comment: Well, I said that I *imagine* they do. Say you have a site with lots of content, you're already using Solr to drive the site search, and you want other sites to be able to search your content. Rather than building a custom API, Solr could make that much simpler...

Answer (score 7):

Exposing a Solr instance to the public internet is a bad idea. Even though you can strip some components to make it read-only, it just wasn't designed with security in mind, it's meant to be used as an internal service, just like you wouldn't expose a RDBMS.

From the [Solr Security wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity):

> First and foremost, Solr does not
>   concern itself with security either at
>   the document level or the
>   communication level. It is strongly
>   recommended that the application
>   server containing Solr be firewalled
>   such the only clients with access to
>   Solr are your own. A default/example
>   installation of Solr allows any client
>   with access to it to add, update, and
>   delete documents (and of course
>   search/read too), including access to
>   the Solr configuration and schema
>   files and the administrative user
>   interface.

Even [ajax-solr](http://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr), a Solr client for javascript meant to run in a browser, [recommends talking to Solr through a proxy](http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/architectural-overview/14).

Take for example [guardian.co.uk](http://www.guardian.co.uk/): it's well-known that [they use Solr for searching](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/04/29/for-the-guardian-solr-is-the-new-database/), but they built an [API](http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform) to let others access their content. This way they can [define](http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform/content-api-content-search-reference-guide) and [control](http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform/faq) exactly what and how they want people to search for things.

Otherwise, any script kiddie can write a trivial loop to DoS your Solr instance and therefore bring down your site.

Comment: Those are good suggestions and hopefully anyone setting up Solr for production would follow these suggestions. But this doesn't really get to the question asked. I'll edit the question to clarify my particular use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just remove the line that defines your solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler in solrconfig.xml.

Replication is a nice way to setup read-only while being able to do indexation. Just setup a master with restricted access and a slave that is read-only (by removing your XmlUpdateRequestHandler from the config). The slave will be replicated from the master but won't accept any indexation directly.

**UPDATE**

I just read that in Solr 1.4, you can [disable component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Enable.2BAC8-disable_components). I just tried it on the /update requestHandler and I was not able to index anymore.

Comment: Apparently commenting out that request handler won't disable anything because it's just acting as an override (according to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler). I guess you could stick in a bogus class for the /update request handler, but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: nice find! i thought this 'disable component' feature was the golden ticket, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to let you disable core components including /select /update and /admin. thanks for your help in looking for a solution.

Comment: you test it? I tried it earlier and, either by removing the requestHandler declaration or using the enable attribute was enough to disabling the /update of my index

Comment: Yeah, I tested it, but I'll try again. Changing the 'enable' attribute definitely worked for custom requestHandlers, but I couldn't get it to disable /update.

Comment: Yep, when 'enable' is set to false Solr just ignores the definition and uses the core handler. Same thing happens when I comment out the whole requestHandler line for /update.

Comment: weird... you use Solr on Tomcat or Jetty? My Solr is running on Tomcat.

Comment: And don't forget that each time you change something in solrconfig.xml, you have to reload your core or restart your webserver

Comment: So I went and tested with a fresh Solr install. I found that commenting out the /update handler or setting it to false initially prevents documents from being added. However, they still get queued up and later committed when Tomcat restarts. So close... :(

Comment: Nope, setting enabled="false" did not work. I think a proxy is the solution.